# Hashicorp Vault API - Create User - unsupported path

Tags: urlencode, hashicorp-vault

Can we create a user in vault API using special characters. For example below POST url is used to create users.

POST : http://localhost:8200/v1/auth/userpass/users/myuser-1@beta_1.0$

Paylod :

```
      {
        "password": "myPassword",
        "policies": "myuser-1@beta_1.0$",
        "ttl": "120",
        "max_ttl": "120"
      }
```

Result :

```
{
    "errors": [
        "1 error occurred:\n\t* unsupported path\n\n"
    ]
}
```

the user **myuser-1@beta_1.0$** contains special characters @ _ $. I think the @ $ chars should be encoded before passing to vault. However there is no information about url encoding in below documentation.

https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/userpass/index.html

Is encoding supported here or should it be replaced with other char before sending it to vault??

Note: Removing @ $ chars, api works fine.